# Is formal methods just writing the same code twice?

Tags: testing, methods, specifications

I’m trying to rap my head around why formal verification is useful? I’ve read that it reduces vulnerabilities in code but I’m puzzled by how it can do that, my understanding is you write a specification in another language that you can use to test your implementation for conformity to the spec but to me that alone wouldn’t make code better? What am I missing? Or is that the whole picture? I’ve read that multilingual people tend to be more logical, is the idea behind formal methods the same? Is it as simple as writing the same problem in two languages force you to think about the problem clearer?

Comment: I think this is could be more appropriate on [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it seems to be not about a specific programming problem with testing, which is what Stack Overflow is for. Please read the linked SQA's help page to know what questions they accept there.

Comment: no luck posting it here https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/49683/is-formal-verification-just-duplicating-the-same-logic-in-two-languages-for-equa incase anyone has feedback! but I'm still very curious about the question